# Fetch two tables combined (not showing wanted result)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

```
$table1 = ("10", "20", "30", "40");
$table2 = ("a", "b", "c", "d");
```

Now i want to fetch these two tables combined. here is my SQL CODE

```
$StatementOne = $_POST['catogry']."edb";
$StatementTwo = "SELECT* FROM ".$_POST['catogry']."ior";

 $sql=mysqli_query($con," ".$StatementTwo." INNER JOIN ".$StatementOne."
ON (".$_POST['catogry']."edb.ImportedItemDescriptionPartName = ".$_POST['catogry']."ior.Make  
AND ".$_POST['catogry']."ior.Vehicle = ".$_POST['catogry']."edb.VehicleModel) 
WHERE Vehicle='".$_POST['vehicle']."' AND Make='".$_POST['meterial']."'
" )or die ('Invalid Query:'. mysqli_error($con));
```

HERE IS MY PHP CODE

```
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

{echo "<form action='edit-entriy.php?id=" . $row['EDBQuotaID'] . "' method='post'     enctype='multipart/form-data' name='myForm'><tr>";echo "<div style=' clear:both;'><div class='programing-page-width'><div class='mysqldata_fetch'><input type='submit' name='EDIT' value='Edit'></div>";
$post="list";
$checkboxes = (isset($_POST[$post]) ? $_POST[$post] : array());
foreach($checkboxes as $value)
{
if ($value == 1)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['PralSerial'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 2)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['EDBQuotaID'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 3)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['Grade'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 4) 
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['ImportedItemDescriptionPartName'] ."  </div>";}

if ($value == 5)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['ManufacturedPartName'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 6)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['Vehicle'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 7)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['HSCode'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 8)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['NoofUnitsAnnum'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 9)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['TotalApprovedQuantity'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 10)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['UnitsAnnum'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 11)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['AsCalculation'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 12)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['SNo'] ."</div>";}

if ($value == 13)
{echo"<div class='mysqldata_fetch'>". $row['Make'] ."</div>";}

}
```

Now I have got result something like this

```
a - 10,
b - 10, 
c - 10, 
d - 10, 
a - 20, 
b - 20, 
c - 20, 
d - 20, 
a - 30, 
b - 30, 
c - 30, 
d - 30, 
a - 40, 
b - 40, 
c - 40, 
d - 40,
```

this is not that result which i wanted. It should be like this.

```
a - 10,
b - 20, 
c - 30, 
d - 40,
```

It is relay hard for me to make you understand my issue hope you can understand and answered my question.

Sorry i am not well in english. I appologise for any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use group by in your sql statement
you can read here about "Group By" http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp